# I'm following a tutorial but finding that my trim lasso tool is performing inconsistently when generating the depth of new shapes. Please help

Tags: sculpting, 3d-cursor

I'm following along with a creature tutorial and the instructor is using the lasso trim tool no problem with the same inputs as below. Sometimes when making a new shape with the lasso, it is flat, like the image below, and sometimes it is 3d and uses my cursor. I have no idea why it is being inconsistent. Could it be that I'm using a tablet to draw?

Edit: Adding another image showing the inconsistency. It wasn't working and then just seemed to start working again after playing with the mirroring and switching what axis we looked at in the view. Then stopped working again. We fiddled with the radius of my pen but it didn't make a difference[image][image]

Comment: Solution: had to do an initial lasso, create a shape away from main work space and after initial shape, the tool started to work correctly

Comment: This isn't a solution, it's a work-around at best.